# Query to return all fields where the next value is 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, class, oop

I have a table which is set up like so:

ID | first_name | first_name_trusted | last_name | last_name_trusted

Except with more fields that follow suit.

This table is for customers, and the data is collected from various sources where the data is more trustworthy than others. E.g. People getting a quote online are likely to give a false email, but ringing up to confirm an appointment will have a high chance that there contact details are legit.

I have made a class which has various methods for customers, one of which is a set_trusted() method.

This method takes an array of fields and updates the data fields with the legit data but also updates the field_name_trusted field with a 1 if its 'trusted'.

What I know need to do is to retrieve all field data where we class it as trusted.

No idea how to set about this though.

In textual:

```
SELECT ALL FIELDS WHERE THE NAME OF THE FIELD ENDS WITH _TRUSTED AND IS A 1.
```

Hope some of this makes sense...

What my current method of returning all data regardless looks like:

```
  /* Return all the customer information in an array */
  function get_allData() {
    $query = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE `id` = '$this->customer_ID'") or die(mysql_error());
    $customerData = array();
    while ($customer = $query->fetch_object()) {
        $customerData[] = array(
            'id' => $customer->id,
            'first_name' => $customer->first_name,
            'last_name' => $customer->last_name,
            'email' => $customer->email,
            'telephone_number' => $customer->telephone_number,
            'address' => $customer->address,
            'post_code' => $customer->post_code,
            'created_at' => $customer->created_at,
        );
    }
    return $customerData;
  }
```

Comment: This is actually a bad idea, but there you go `SHOW FIELDS FROM your_table WHERE Field LIKE '%\_TRUSTED'`

Comment: I like your thinking on this one. Slightly different though, is that I only want the fields ending with _trusted and have a value of 1 and they belong to a specific row with a given ID.

Comment: Then in the first step use the `SHOW FIELDS` querry and build your second query of it. you can't do this in one query I think. And you cannot select a field only if it's 1.